# Codechef - NZEC Error in python code

Tags: python

The code runs fine on my machine, but when i compile it on codechef it gives a NZEC(Runtime Error).

The link to the problem : https://www.codechef.com/problems/PPTEST

About my solution: I have calculated the percentile of each test case based on their time and point values. Then I have sorted the entries in each test case based on the percentile.

```
import sys
def check(x):
    if not(x in range(1,100)):
        sys.exit(1)
T = input()
check(T)

N_W = []
C_P_T = {}
tp = []
tt = []

for i in range(0,T):
    tp.append(0)
    tt.append(0)
    N_W.append(map(int, raw_input().split())) 

    check(N_W[i][0])
    check(N_W[i][1]) 

    C_P_T[i] = []
    for j in range(0,N_W[i][0]):
        C_P_T[i].append(map(int, raw_input().split()))

        check(C_P_T[i][j][0])
        check(C_P_T[i][j][1])
        check(C_P_T[i][j][2])

        C_P_T[i][j].append(N_W[i][1]-C_P_T[i][j][2])
        C_P_T[i][j].append(C_P_T[i][j][1]*C_P_T[i][j][0])
        C_P_T[i][j].pop(0)
        C_P_T[i][j].pop(0)
        C_P_T[i][j].pop(0)
        tp[i]+= C_P_T[i][j][1]
        tt[i]+=C_P_T[i][j][0]


for i in range(0,T):
    C_P_T[i].sort(key = lambda x : x[0] , reverse = True)
    item_time = C_P_T[i][0][0]
    percentile_time = (C_P_T[i][0][0]/float(tt[i]))*((len(C_P_T[i])-1)/float(len(C_P_T[i])))

    for j in range(0,N_W[i][0]):
        if C_P_T[i][j][0] == item_time:
            C_P_T[i][j].append(percentile_time)
        else:
            item_time = C_P_T[i][j][0]
            percentile_time = (C_P_T[i][j][0]/float(tt[i]))*((len(C_P_T[i])-j-1)/float(len(C_P_T[i])))
            C_P_T[i][j].append(percentile_time)

for i in range(0,T):
    C_P_T[i].sort(key = lambda x : x[1] , reverse = True)
    item_points = C_P_T[i][0][1]
    percentile_points = (C_P_T[i][0][1]/float(tp[i]))*((len(C_P_T[i])-1)/float(len(C_P_T[i])))

    for j in range(0,N_W[i][0]):
        if C_P_T[i][j][1] == item_points:
            C_P_T[i][j].append(percentile_points)
        else:
            item_points = C_P_T[i][j][1]
            percentile_points = ((C_P_T[i][j][1])/float(tp[i]))*((len(C_P_T[i])-j-1)/float(len(C_P_T[i])))
            C_P_T[i][j].append(percentile_points)

    C_P_T[i][j].append(C_P_T[i][j][2]+C_P_T[i][j][3])
    C_P_T[i][j].append(N_W[i][1]-C_P_T[i][j][0])
    C_P_T[i][j].pop(2)
    C_P_T[i][j].pop(2)

    C_P_T[i].sort(key = lambda x : x[2],reverse = True)

for i in range(0,T):
    points = 0
    for j in range(0,N_W[i][0]):
        if N_W[i][1]-C_P_T[i][j][3] >= 0:
            points+=C_P_T[i][j][1]
            N_W[i][1]-=C_P_T[i][j][3]
    print points
```

Comment: Can you try to isolate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

NZEC means "non-zero exit code", so that is probably happening in `sys.exit(1)` in your `check()` function.  What you are receiving from `input()` is either not an integer or not in the right range.

**Update**:  I notice that you use `range(1, 100)` for validity testing.

But the problem description at codechef states that `1 ≤ T ≤ 100`.  That is equivalent to `range(1, 101)`

So, codechef could be passing your code a perfectly valid 100, and your code would reject it, probably with the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: @Patrick_Maupin I have tried converting T to integer, no success. I am using python 2.7 and when I compile on codechef, I select 2.7 on that too.